# THREE.Js How acess a object outside the OBJMTLLoader

Tags: three.js

Does anybody knows how can i acess a object outside a OBJMTLLoader

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.load( obj, mtl, function ( object ) {
object.position.set(0,0,0);
scene.add( object );
});

console.log(object);
```

inside of the function objects = THREE.Object3D but outside is equal do ObjectLoad.

Thanks for everybody.

Comment: just declare a variable outside the loader-function scope?

Comment: I try this already but didnt work. The variable appears undefined.

Comment: well, of course because loading is asynchronous and it will be undefined until the obj is loaded. you will have to check like   "if (object !== undefined) then do stuff with the object, this of course can only be done in the (game) loop.

Answer (score 1):

The object is simply inside the scope of the undefined function.

Set the function to return the object

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.load( obj, mtl, function ( object ) {

object.position.set(0,0,0);

return object;//here
});

scene.add( object );
console.log(object);
```